# How do I verified the user authority level in java

Tags: java, sqlite, javafx

I have an SQL table where is stores user, password and the user role/authority level, Admins=5, normal users=1. Right now, I'm not sure how to pass the information that I have got from my getUserRole method into the login event handler, since its an Int method and you cant return a boolean type variable to it from an int or is there a better way to rework the code to make it simpler?

**Login Method**

```java
public boolean isLogin(String user, String pass) throws Exception{
        PreparedStatement pr = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;

        String sql = "SELECT * FROM Login where username = ? and password = ?";

        try{
            pr = this.connection.prepareStatement(sql);
            pr.setString(1, user);
            pr.setString(2, pass);

            rs = pr.executeQuery();

             if(rs.next()){
                 rs.getInt("role");


             return true;   
            }
            return false;
        }
        catch(SQLException ex){
            return false;
        }

        finally{
                pr.close();
                rs.close();
        }

    }
```

**Get User Authority Method**

```java
public int getUserRole(String user) throws Exception
    {
     PreparedStatement pr = null;
     ResultSet rs = null;

     String sql = "SELECT * FROM Login WHERE username = ? AND role = ?";
     try
     {
         pr = this.connection.prepareStatement(sql);
         pr.setString(1, user);


         if(rs.next())
         {
             int role = rs.getInt("role");
             return role;
         }
         else{
             return 0;
         }
     }
     catch(SQLException ex)
     {
         return 0;
     }

     finally
     {
     pr.close();
     rs.close();
     }


    }
```

**And Finally the controller, the login event handler**

```java
@FXML
    public void Login (ActionEvent event){
        try{
            if(this.loginModel.isLogin(this.username.getText(), this.password.getText())){
                Stage stage = (Stage) this.login.getScene().getWindow();
                stage.close();


                if(this.loginModel.getUserRole(this.username.getText()))//error is here,
 cant get username as its a boolean type and not int
        }
      }
catch (Exception localException)
         {
             this.loginStatus.setText("The username or password entered is incorrect. Please check and try again.");
         }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Authentication and authorization should be two separate steps. This means that login should not worry about getting a role. Instead, when the user attempts to access a resource, that is the time to check if the user's role allows access to the resource.

After a closer look at your code, it appears that you are doing this and are having trouble with the `if` condition. You need to determine what `int` value is given to each role. In particular, what value means that the user is an "admin user"? When you know this value, you need to do a comparison with `==`.

Comment: well the thing is that if it detects its an admin login, it would show an admin jframe instead, if its a normal user, it would only display the normal user jframe, so i need to know how to do that

Comment: @User2382 See my edit for some more suggestions about how you should fix your code.

Comment: Well that i understand, right now Im having problem with getting it to the event handler as both the method and the event handler are in different java files, so how should I pass the info the event handler function?

Comment: @User2382 You don't need to pass anything. You need to compare the return value of `this.loginModel.getUserRole()` with whatever value represents an admin user.

Comment: something like `if(this.loginMode.getUserRole(this.username.getInt()) == '5')` ? or is it something else

Comment: @User2382 Close. Instead of `getInt()` use `getText()` as you did in your original code. And instead of `'5'` use `5` since `getuserRole()` returns an `int` not a `char`.

Comment: Ah cool thanks, the error is gone now, but there one more problem I had is that it doesn't prompt it to the respective screen according to the user role given when it should. The login jframe just close when it has finished verifying the user and pass.

Comment: @User2382 It sounds like you need to write the code to show the correct JFrame. If you need further help, post a new question with code showing what you are trying to do.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55746184/how-to-get-the-respective-jframe-according-to-the-user-type here is the question if you have time to take a look at it