# How to get the respective stage according to the user type?

Tags: java, sqlite, javafx, scenebuilder

So the problem right now is that I have issue with prompting towards the right stage for each type of users, I have a method which checks their username and return their type of role and after that it will prompt it to their respective stage after verifying their user and pass.

I have tried to do some debug and it seems that the method getUserRole has something wrong with it, since I can't get into the method for it in the login controller.

**Login Controller*

```
@FXML
    public void Login(ActionEvent event) {
        try {
            if (this.loginModel.isLogin(this.username.getText(), this.password.getText())) {
                Stage stage = (Stage) this.login.getScene().getWindow();
                stage.close();

                if (this.loginModel.getUserRole(this.username.getText()) == 5) {
                    adminLogin();
                } else if (this.loginModel.getUserRole(this.username.getText()) == 4) {
                    technicianLogin();
                } else if (this.loginModel.getUserRole(this.username.getText()) == 3) {
                    custServiceLogin();
                } else if (this.loginModel.getUserRole(this.username.getText()) == 3) {
                    financeLogin();
                } else if (this.loginModel.getUserRole(this.username.getText()) == 3) {
                    managementLogin();
                } else {
                    this.loginStatus.setText("The username or password entered is incorrect. Please check and try again.");
                }

            }
        } catch (Exception localException) {
            this.loginStatus.setText("The username or password entered is incorrect. Please check and try again.");
        }
    }
```

**Get UserRole Method**

```
public int getUserRole(String user) throws Exception
    {
     PreparedStatement pr = null;
     ResultSet rs = null;

     String sql = "SELECT * FROM Login WHERE username = ? AND role = ?";
     try
     {
         pr = this.connection.prepareStatement(sql);
         pr.setString(1, user);


         if(rs.next())//cant initialized this if statement
         {
             int role = rs.getInt("role");
             return role;
         }
         else{
             return 0;
         }
     }
     catch(SQLException ex)
     {
         return 0;
     }

     finally
     {
     pr.close();
     rs.close();
     }


    }
```

Comment: There are 2 placeholders in the query, but you only set one. This way you'll ALWAYS get an exception when calling `pr.executeQuery()`. Probably a change of the query would fix the issue: `String sql = "SELECT role FROM Login WHERE username = ?";` (I'm pretty sure this is a duplicate which is why I don't post this as an answer.) BTW: I recommend storing the result of the query/using a `switch` instead of querying the db up to 3 times (or 5 times, if you check for 5 different values).

Comment: do you get an exception or is your debugger not stopping at a cetain breakpoint you expect it to? - Your question lets me think it might be: your loginmodel is not initialized

Comment: Does this project include `Swing`? Is `JFrame` the correct wording here?

Comment: jframe, i used javafx for this one, its in the tag, @sedrick

Comment: Ya initialized is probably the better word for it, as it did not go went into the if statement @KnusperPudding

Comment: I tried your suggestion @fabian, but it didnt quite work for me, as the outcome is the same, no jframe is loaded after that

Comment: So if you are not using `Swing`, `JFrame` is probably not the word to be using. `JavaFX` has no `JFrame`.

Comment: right ok, so i used `stage` instead would be a better word for `javafx`, since im using `scenebuilder` to do the GUI? @Sedrick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, it have seems that i have forgot to execute the query, after its added into the try block, it seems to have work.

```
rs.executeQuery();
```